# Strong parameters nested form for has_many attachments using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a rails 4 application with the following models:

**section.rb**

```
belongs_to :page
belongs_to :user

has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true
```

**asset.rb**

```
belongs_to :section

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
    :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

and... **sections_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @section = @page.sections.new(section_params)
  @section.user = current_user

  if @section.save
    redirect_to page_sections_url(@page), notice: "'#{@section.name}' has been created successfully."
  else
    flash[:alert] =  "Uh oh! Looks like something went wrong" 
    render 'index'  
  end
end
```

So my question... How can I implement strong parameters for this? I have the following parameters showing up as output:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"......=", "section"=>{"assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"attachment"=>#, @original_filename="calculator.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"section[assets_attributes][0][attachment]\"; filename=\"calculator.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}, "name"=>"Foo", "content_md"=>"Bar"}, "commit"=>"Create Section", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sections", "page_id"=>"about"}
```

and the following errors: `Unpermitted parameters: assets_attributes`.. when I append `assets_attributes: {}` to the list, I get `Unpermitted parameters: attachment`..but how do I do nesting?

**EDIT: forgot the view**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@page, @section], html: {multipart: true , class: 'form-horizontal inplace-new '} do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |asset_fields| %>
        <%= asset_fields.file_field :attachment %>
```

Also.. `asset_fields.input :attachment, as: :file` does not work.. but `file_field` does, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in the implementation of `section_params` add the following

```
params.require(:sections).permit(
  :utf8,
  :authenticity_token,
  :section [
    :assets
  ],etc...)
```